# Как лучше задавать число пробелов в табе - в виде значения переменной или в виде именованной константы?

Tags: c, текст, форматирование

Книга Язык программирования Си. Денис Ритчи упражнение 1.20:

> Напишите программу detab, заменяющую символы табуляции во вводимом
>   тексте нужным числом пробелов (до следующего "стопа" табуляции).
>   Предполагается, что "стопы" табуляции расставлены на фиксированном
>   расстоянии друг от друга, скажем, через n позиций. Как лучше задавать
>   n - в виде значения переменной или в виде именованной константы?

**Вопрос:** Правильно ли я понял задание?

В Википедии сказано, что табуляция это 8 знакомест. Как бы табуляция это константное число знакомест. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

*Я задание понял так*: если введена табуляция, заменить ее на 8 пробелов. И мне не понятно, зачем в задании указывать на каком расстоянии друг от друга стопы табуляции?

И что такое "стопы" табуляции? Стоп и символ табуляции это одно и то же?

Я смотрел другие решения в интернете, у других людей, почему-то, количество пробелов заменяемых на табуляцию, в разных вводимых строках - разное...

Comment: Так о чем вопрос? "Как лучше задавать число пробелов в табе"? Или "что такое табуляция"? Почему в заголовок вопроса вынесено "Как лучше задавать...", но в дальнейшем об этом речи не идет и в качестве принятого отмечен ответ, в котором ни слова об этом не сказано?

Comment: В задании Д. Ритчи спрашивает, как лучше в тексте программы хранить "стопы", т.е. позиции в строке на которые перемещается "курсор" (текущая позиция в выходном тексте в которою надо поместить очередной символ) при считывании символа `\t`. Довольно очевидно, что **переменная лучше**, т.к. позволяет написать более гибкую программу. Если взять текстовую константу, то для получения программы, которая выводит текст со "стопами" кратными, например, 4 (а первоначальный вариант был для 8) программу надо будет *перетранслировать*. Переменную  же можно устанавливать из аргумента запуска.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса "Как лучше задавать число пробелов в табе - в виде значения переменной или в виде именованной константы?" писал не я, мне изменили его сами модераторы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, вы неверно понимаете, что такое табуляция. Но проще пояснить на примере.

Вот, например, имеем:

```
Это текст с пробелами
И еще один текст
Все они выровнены
```

Вы предлагаете:

```
Это        текст        с        пробелами
И        еще        один        текст
Все        они        выровнены
```

Правильно:

```
0       0       1       2
0       8       6       4

Это     текст   с       пробелами
И       еще     один    текст
Все     они     выровнены
```

Так понятно? Табулятор вносит столько пробелов, чтоб новое слово шло с очередной *позиции табуляции*, в данном случае - кратной 8 (что не обязательно, и вряд ли в Википедии сказано, что это строго 8. Скорее что-то вроде "распространенное значение - 8").

Comment: Я сейчас печатал в блокноте Windows, и понял. Там табуляция это 8 пробелов. Когда я ввожу например:"123(и жму tab)", добавляется 5 пробелов. А я этого не знал за всё время пользования компьютером.(а компом я пользуюсь с детства...). Я думал при нажатии Tab всегда добавляется 8 пробелов. Теперь понял, спасибо!

Comment: Это пошло еще со времен механических пишущих машинок, были там такие клавиши... :)

Comment: а зачем в задании нам говорят, что символы табуляции расставлены на фиксированном расстоянии друг от друга?

Comment: Не символы, а "стопы" - позиции табуляции...

Comment: @Harry, а где же ответ на вопрос -- *константа или переменная?*

Comment: @avp Формально "число пробелов в табе" (не размер табуляции), как очевидно следует из ответа, есть величина переменная... :)

Comment: @Harry, нда, Ритчи наверное поймет ответ на свой вопрос, насчет основной массы посетителей ruSO не уверен (впрочем, это не важно, т.к. писать Unix им не грозит).